# How to faithfully redirect console output of a certain tool in powershell?

Tags: powershell, redirect, character-encoding

I use [nuget-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuget-tree) to inspect the nuget dependencies in our code. It produces output like this:

```
C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> $p |? { Test-Path "$_\..\packages.config" } | select -First 1 |% { pushd "$_\.."; "$_" ; nuget-tree.cmd --showSystem ; popd }
C:\xyz\tip\BI\a8i\a8i.csproj
packages.config
└── Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2

C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]>
```

[image]

I would like to save the output to file, but I can't figure out what encoding to use to preserve the nice hierarchy ascii art. Please, observe:

```
C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> $p |? { Test-Path "$_\..\packages.config" } | select -First 1 |% { pushd "$_\.."; "$_" ; nuget-tree.cmd --showSystem ; popd } | Out-File c:\temp\1.txt ; cat c:\temp\1.txt
C:\xyz\tip\BI\a8i\a8i.csproj
packages.config
ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2

C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> $p |? { Test-Path "$_\..\packages.config" } | select -First 1 |% { pushd "$_\.."; "$_" ; nuget-tree.cmd --showSystem ; popd } | Out-File c:\temp\1.txt -Encoding ascii ; cat c:\temp\1.txt
C:\xyz\tip\BI\a8i\a8i.csproj
packages.config
????????? Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2

C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> $p |? { Test-Path "$_\..\packages.config" } | select -First 1 |% { pushd "$_\.."; "$_" ; nuget-tree.cmd --showSystem ; popd } | Out-File c:\temp\1.txt -Encoding unicode ; cat c:\temp\1.txt
C:\xyz\tip\BI\a8i\a8i.csproj
packages.config
ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2

C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> $p |? { Test-Path "$_\..\packages.config" } | select -First 1 |% { pushd "$_\.."; "$_" ; nuget-tree.cmd --showSystem ; popd } | Out-File c:\temp\1.txt -Encoding utf8 ; cat c:\temp\1.txt
C:\xyz\tip\BI\a8i\a8i.csproj
packages.config
ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.2

C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]>
```

How can it be done (except for copy/paste of the console window content) ?

Comment: try using `Add-Content` OR `Set-Content` ... i think your problem is the way that  `Out-File` tags the output file. i _think_ the 1st two include a ByteOrderMark and the 3rd one does not ... but i may have that reversed.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: The problem happens _before_ the output is sent to a file: on Windows, the UTF-8-encoded Node.js output is misinterpreted when PowerShell reads it into strings _in memory_, due to instead assuming that the output is OEM code page-encoded, based on the default value of `cp` / `[console]::OutputEncoding`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Node.js-based CLIs output *UTF-8*-encoded text**, so you must set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` (temporarily) to that encoding to ensure that PowerShell reads the output correctly:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
```

Once read by PowerShell, you can use `>` / `Out-File` to write the text to a flie using UTF-16LE ("Unicode"; Windows PowerShell) / BOM-less UTF-8 (PowerShell Core), or use `Set-Content -Encoding Unicode` or `Set-Content -Encoding Utf8`, though note that the latter will create a file *with* BOM in Windows PowerShell.

---

Note that direct-to-console output, in which case no interpretation by PowerShell is involved, may *display* the characters correctly, irrespective of what `[Console]::OutputEncoding` is set to.

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58438716/45375).

Comment: @mark: I see; ideally, you'd use an option that prevents colored output to begin with, but that doesn't seem to exist in this case; stripping the codes after the fact is probably nontrivial, if it is support all possible VT sequences; certainly worth a new question.