# Powershell string variable with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, windows-10, youtube-dl

I checked many related questions about this, but I couldn't find something that solves my problem. Basically, I want to store a UTF-8 encoded string in a variable and then use that string as a file name.

For example, I'm trying to download a YouTube video. If we print the video title, the non-English characters show up (`ytd` here is [`youtube-dl`](http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/)):

`./ytd https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWYndKw_zbw -e`

Output: `[LEEPLAY] 시티팝 입문 City Pop MIX (Playlist)`

But if I store this in a variable and print it, the Korean characters are ignored:

`$vtitle= ./ytd https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWYndKw_zbw -e`

`$vtitle`

Output:`[LEEPLAY]   City Pop MIX (Playlist)`

Comment: Have you tried it in the ISE?  It might be working, but the console can't display it.  (or OSX)

Comment: @js2010: There is no _display_ problem here - as stated, the characters display fine in the console _when printed directly_. The real problem is a _character-encoding mismatch_ when PowerShell reads the output into .NET strings.
That problem would arise in the ISE as well. Speaking of: Have I ever mentioned that [the ISE is obsolescent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [should be avoided going forward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section)?

Comment: @mklement0 My experience copying and pasting the string, storing to a variable, and creating a file, all worked better in the ISE.  The ISE is hardly obsolete, since it comes with the current version of Windows 10 and powershell 5.1.  Btw, I tried downloading ytd and Cisco Amp quarantined it as a virus.  It could be a false positive, but I would be cautious.

Comment: @js2010: The ISE never was a substitute for the regular console window, and while it provided a great editing experience, its differing behavior always caused headaches. I said _obsolescent_ (not obsolete), because (a) it will receive no future development effort except for critical fixes, (b) it doesn't support PowerShell _Core_ - and we're on the brink of PowerShell Core v7, meant to supersede Windows PowerShell.

Comment: @js2010 `ytd` here refers to `youtube-dl`, which is an open source program and is not a virus. It shouldn't be confused with the other program called "YTD Downloader", which is an ad-filled garbage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>For a **comprehensive overview of how PowerShell interacts with external programs**, which includes **sending data *to* them**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59118502/45375).</sup>

**When PowerShell interprets output *from external programs*** (such as `ytd` in your case), **it assumes that the output uses the character encoding reflected in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`**.

Note:

- *Interpreting* refers to cases where PowerShell *captures* (e.g., `$output = ...`), *relays* (e.g., `... | Select-String ...`), or *redirects* (e.g., `... > output.txt`) the external program's output.
- By contrast, printing *directly to the display* may not be affected, because PowerShell then isn't involved, and certain CLIs adjust their behavior when their stdout isn't redirected to print directly to the console with full Unicode support (which explains why the characters looked as expected in your console when `ytd`'s output printed directly to it).

If the encoding reported by `[Console]::OutputEncoding` is not the same encoding used by the external program at hand, PowerShell *misinterprets* the output.

**To fix that, you must (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding]` to match the encoding used by the external program**.

For instance, let's assume an executable `foo.exe` that outputs UTF-8-encoded text:

```
# Save the current encoding and switch to UTF-8.
$prev = [Console]::OutputEncoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()

# PowerShell now interprets foo's output correctly as UTF-8-encoded.
# and $output will correctly contain CJK characters.
$output = foo https://example.org -e

# Restore the previous encoding.
[Console]::OutputEncoding = $prev
```

**Important**:

- **`[Console]::OutputEncoding` by default** reflects the encoding associated with the legacy system locale's **OEM code page**, as reported by `chcp` (e.g. `437` on US-English systems).

  - **Recent versions of Windows 10 now allow setting the system locale to code page `65001` (UTF-8)** (the feature is still in beta as of Window 10 version 1909), which is great, considering that **most modern command-line utilities "speak" UTF-8** - but note that making **this *system-wide* change has far-reaching consequences** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).

---

With the specific program at hand, [`youtube-dl`](http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/), [js2010 has discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58451934/45375) that capturing in a variable works without extra effort if you pass `--encoding utf-16`.

The reason this works is that the resulting UTF16-LE-encoded output is *preceded by a BOM* (Byte-Order Mark).

(Note that `--encoding utf-8` does *not* work, because `youtube-dl` then does *not* emit a BOM.)

*Windows PowerShell* is capable of detecting and properly decoding UTF-16LE-encoded and UTF-8-encoded text *irrespective of the effective `[Console]::OutputEncoding]`* IF AND ONLY IF the output is preceded by a BOM.

**Caveats**:

- This does *not* work in PowerShell *Core* (v6+, on any of the supported platforms).
- Even in Windows PowerShell you'll rarely be able to take advantage of this obscure behavior, because using a BOM in *stdout output* is *atypical* (it is typically only used in *files*).

Comment: I had to add `--encoding utf-8` as an argument to the program to get this to work, so I'm guessing `youtube-dl` doesn't output in UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in the ISE.  Youtube-dl is from ytdl-org.github.io.  Actually the ise wouldn't be needed, but the filename will only show correctly in something like explorer.

```bsh
# get title
# utf-16 has a bom, or use utf-8-sig, this program is python based
$a = .\youtube-dl -e https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qpy7N4oFQUQ --encoding utf-16
$a
Gacharic Spin - 赤裸ライアー教則映像(short ver.)TOMO-ZO編
```

You might have similar luck in vscode (or osx/linux).

Comment: +1 for a simpler solution, but it's important to note that while it works with the particular program at hand, `youtube-dl`, it will rarely work in other cases: (a) it fundamentally works in Windows PowerShell only, not in PowerShell Core; and (b) it 
is atypical for programs to emit a BOM when writing to stdout, which the technique depends on. It doesn't work with `--encoding utf-8`, because `youtube-dl` then doesn't emit a BOM.