# Powershell - Write-Output produces string with a BOM character

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute such command in a Powershell script:

`Write-Output "Some Command" | some-application`

When running PS script `some-application` receives string `\xef\xbb\xbfSome Command`. The first character is an UTF-8 BOM. All solutions that I can Google, apply only to redirecting output to a file. But I'm trying to redirect a string to another command (via pipe).

The variable $OutputEncoding shows that ASCII is configured, no UTF-8 is set.

I'm running this script from Azure DevOps Pipeline and only there this problem exists.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8) can help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PowerShell to write a file in UTF-8 without the BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom)

Answer (score 0):

Note: This answer deals with **how to control the encoding that PowerShell uses** when **data is *piped to* an *external program*** (to be read via *stdin* by such a program).

This **is *separate from***:

- what character encoding *PowerShell cmdlets* use by default *on output* - for more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).
- what character encoding PowerShell uses when reading data *received from* external programs - for more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58438716/45375).

---

**The implication is that you've mistakenly set the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding)**, which determines what character encoding PowerShell uses to send data *to* external programs, **to a UTF-8 encoding *with a BOM***.

Your problem goes away if you assign a *BOM-less* UTF-8 encoding instead:

```
$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new($false) # BOM-less

"Some Command" | some-application
```

Note that this problem wouldn't arise in *PowerShell [Core] v6+*, where `$OutputEncoding` *defaults* to BOM-less UTF-8 (in *Windows PowerShell*, unfortunately, it defaults to ASCII).

---

To illustrate the problem:

```
$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Utf8 # *with* BOM

"Some Command" | findstr .
```

The above outputs `∩╗┐Some Command`, where `∩╗┐` is the rendering of the 3-byte UTF-8 BOM (`0xef`, `0xbb`, `0xbf`) in the OEM code page `437` (on US-English systems, for instance).