# How to properly use redirection with accentuated characters in a powershell shell?

Tags: powershell

I haven't found a way to properly generate files with accentuated character when forced to use redirection in a powershell shell.

example, this:  `curl https://www.microsoft.com/fr-ca/ | out-file test.txt`
will produce result like this in the file(the right result should be "productivité"

> productivit├®

I tried many variations with the -encoding flag, like  `out-file test.txt -Encoding utf8BOM`, but they all gave bad results too

Using the CMD shell is not an option as I require to run in a powershell shell.

Any ideas how to do this properly?

Comment: if you get the expected results with CMD, then you should use the same encoding in powershell.  Just specify -Enconding oem

Comment: Try `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` before calling curl. Works for me on PS 7.2.

Comment: Curl is causing me to get the same encoding. You can use the available PowerShell tools to do this with the desired results and without changing the console encoding `(iwr https://www.microsoft.com/fr-ca/).Content | Out-File test.txt` [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2) - * Works on PowerShell 7.1.5 and 5.1.

Comment: In short: While the output from external programs may _print_ OK to the _console_, when it comes to _capturing the output in a variable or redirecting it_, PowerShell decodes the output into .NET strings, using the character encoding stored in `[Console]::OutputEncoding`. Therefore, you may have to (temporarily) set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to the encoding used by the external program. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58438716/45375) to the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: For Information: curl from a command line is not the same as curl from powershell, the latter is just an alias for Invoke-WebRequest

Comment: As a pragmatic shortcut, you could also use `cmd /c 'curl https://www.microsoft.com/fr-ca/ > test.txt'`, taking advantage of the fact that `cmd.exe` passes the raw output through to the output file.

Comment: @DavidMartin, that is true for _Windows PowerShell_ (where you need to use `curl.exe` if you truly want to call the external program), but no longer for _PowerShell (Core) 7+_, where the `curl` alias has been removed (so as not to shadow `curl.exe`).

Comment: You can use -outfile to save it, but it looks like a plain ascii html file to me.

Comment: Many comments have a working solution, thanks! None of them are as clean as I had hoped but it brings solutions to many use-case, either from the shell, or from a script.
`[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` seems to fix it in the shell for about all the programs I tried, that's a nice one to keep :)   And inside script, indeed I should use Invoke-Webrequest instead.  Somehow, I always forget about that one and always use curl or wget.